# Download files with AFNetworking, check for updates (Etag, last modified)

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I've been searching around documentations and also the web, but I am still unsure how to do this right:

I have a large number of files that I want to download and store locally to display them in my app (PDFs, images in various resolutions, ...)
I have a number of requirements:

- The files need to be available in offline conditions.
- The files need to be up to date (check for new versions of the file regularly like twice a day)
- I need access to the local file `URL`, not only a `NSData` memory representation of the file
- the local files should never be deleted automatically, only through user interaction.

I am supporting iOS 6.1+.

I am using AFNetworking (currently 1.1)

I have control of the hosting server, so I can set appropriate http headers.

This is what the process should be like:
Example: UI requires resource

- check if resource is available at local path, if yes load resource from local path
- check server for new version, HEAD request
- compare Etag or modified date with local version
- download file if it has been updated
- replace local file
- notify the UI that a new version can be loaded from the local path

Now my question is, how should I implement this given the requirements?

Specifically, which parts of this can be done by `NSURLConnection / AFNetworking`, which parts do I have to implement myself?